# Stata or SPSS function for calculating quintiles means

Tags: stata, spss

Please let me know how to calculate the means for the following quintiles in SPSS or STATA.

250
385
490
320
180

Comment: You are showing 5 numbers and you could calculate their mean. Somehow I doubt that is what you want, but what you do want is not clear to me. You would need to say much more about your data to make this a clear question. I am a Stata person but I suspect that an SPSS person would be just as uncertain about what you want.

Comment: spss person. check.

Comment: my guess is that those numbers represent the OP's threshold cutpoints and they want to calculate the mean within each band.  That said, deductive reasoning really shouldn't extend that far...

Comment: @user45392 They aren't even in order....  Also, 5 breakpoints define 6 classes. You may be right, and I remain puzzled.

Comment: Dear @Nick Cox, sorry, let me clear it more, those numbers are "number of children ever born" in each quintile here income groups (poorest, poor, middle, rich, richest) respectively.  what I don't know is how to calculate the mean and std for each quintile? not for groups.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want the mean and SD of some variable by some grouping variable. Those numbers are hardly relevant, as they are totals or counts of some other variable. In either program, use of the menu and/or documentation is a good idea. In Stata, `summarize`, `tabulate`, `table`, `tabstat` are some possibilities. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for advice on how to ask a question, as this falls far short of the minimum for a good question.

Answer (score -1):

There are various places in SPSS or Stata where one can compute means and standard deviations, including for data broken down into groups such as quintiles. In SPSS the MEANS procedure is one option, EXAMINE (Explore in the menus) is another, but in all cases you have to have a variable for each group or quintile that varies over cases within that group or quintile. If you have only one value of the "variable" of interest, then the mean is just that value and the standard deviation is undefined using the common formula, or 0 using the square root of the maximum likelihood estimate of the population variance (which uses N in the denominator instead of the usual N-1).